# How to get beamerarticle and polytable to play nicely?

Tags: beamerarticle

I have some LaTeX which formats correctly when using beamer and polytable but not when using beamerarticle (and polytable). I tried the suggestion in 21.2.1 of the Beamer User Guide but although I get the correct line break this adds two extra "all"s.

Here is what I get with beamer

[image: beamer]

Here is what I get with beamerarticle

[image: beamerarticle]

And here is what I get using the suggestion in 21.2.1 of the Beamer User Guide

[image: beamerarticle + <all>]

Here is the latex code

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\ReadOnlyOnce[1]{\@ifundefined{#1}{\@namedef{#1}{}}\SkipToFmtEnd}

\newcommand{\Sp}{\hskip.33334em\relax}

\newcommand{\Conid}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand{\Varid}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\usepackage{polytable}

\@ifundefined{mathindent}%
  {\newdimen\mathindent\mathindent\leftmargini}%
  {}%

\def\resethooks{%
  \global\let\SaveRestoreHook\empty
  \global\let\ColumnHook\empty}
\newcommand*{\savecolumns}[1][default]%
  {\g@addto@macro\SaveRestoreHook{\savecolumns[#1]}}
\newcommand*{\restorecolumns}[1][default]%
  {\g@addto@macro\SaveRestoreHook{\restorecolumns[#1]}}
\newcommand*{\aligncolumn}[2]%
  {\g@addto@macro\ColumnHook{\column{#1}{#2}}}

\resethooks

\newcommand{\hsindent}[1]{\quad}
\let\hspre\empty
\let\hspost\empty

\newcommand{\hsnewpar}[1]%
  {{\parskip=0pt\parindent=0pt\par\vskip #1\noindent}}

\newcommand{\hscodestyle}{}

\newcommand{\sethscode}[1]%
  {\expandafter\let\expandafter\hscode\csname #1\endcsname
   \expandafter\let\expandafter\endhscode\csname end#1\endcsname}

\newenvironment{plainhscode}%
  {\hsnewpar\abovedisplayskip
   \advance\leftskip\mathindent
   \hscodestyle
   \let\hspre\(\let\hspost\)%
   \pboxed}%
  {\endpboxed%
   \hsnewpar\belowdisplayskip
   \ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\plainhs}{\sethscode{plainhscode}}
\plainhs

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Population Growth}
Here is some text.
\begin{hscode}\SaveRestoreHook
\column{B}{@{}>{\hspre}l<{\hspost}@{}}%
\column{E}{@{}>{\hspre}l<{\hspost}@{}}%
\>[B]{}\Varid{f}\mathbin{::}\Conid{Double}\to \Conid{Double}{}\<[E]%
\\<all>
\>[B]{}\Varid{f}\;\Varid{x}\mathrel{=}\Varid{x}{}\<[E]%
\ColumnHook
\end{hscode}\resethooks
And some more.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```